# How do I determine a variable's data type? How to convert to string?

Tags: variables, types, applescript

I have two questions...

Here is a really simple example script which causes an error:

*System Events got an error: Can’t make item 1 of every application process whose visible = true into type string.*

```
tell application "System Events"
   repeat with appProc in (every application process whose visible is true)
       display dialog appProc
   end repeat
end tell
```

## 1- How do I determine the data type of a variable?

This would be helpful for future reference so I can figure out what kind of data type I am dealing with

## 2- How do I convert the above data type to a string so it displays with display dialog?

I tried adding:

```
appProc as string
```

but then I get another error that says:

*Can’t make «class pcap» "myapplication" of application "System Events" into type string.*

Comment: An application process has various properties contained in a record - are you wanting to display a particular item or the whole record?

Comment: Honestly I don't know! I am still trying to figure AppleScript out, so when I have a varibale like appProc and I obviously can't display it as a string, I do not know what appProc is, so that is what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**To get the data type**... use class...

```
set a to "some text variable"
return class of a
```

**Convert to string?**... try "as text" or "as string". It mostly works. However in your case appProc has properties (as Red_menace mentioned) and you want to display its name property...

```
display dialog (name of appProc)
```